# Python installation

Tags: python

i have a machine with two users accounts.

i installed python in the first account without any problem but when am gone to install into the second account it cause the following error

```
checking for C compiler default output file name... configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

caused when execute the following command:

```
./configure --prefix="/home/df/python5"
```

i don't why ? could anyone help me

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

When you execute ./configure in what folder you are (absolute path) ?

Check if this folder and sub-folders are read-writable for your "second" user account.

Seems you have no write access ...

Anyway, why do you want to install the same python two times ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the contents of `config.log`, it lists what commands the `configure` script is trying to execute in order to find out where your C compiler is and what parameters it supports. Search for the error message in the log file, scroll a few lines up and you should see what commands were executed that led to this error message. Maybe it helps you figure out why the script is not able to find a suitable C compiler.

For instance, this is the line I see in a `config.log` file on my computer corresponding to the test that failed for you:

```
configure:2827: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:2854: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
configure:2857: $? = 0
configure:2895: result: a.out
```

For the record, `$? = 0` means that the command was executed successfully.